# FB is not defined error in Cordova/Ionic App

Tags: cordova, facebook-javascript-sdk, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am aware that receiving the following error is a common problem:

`ReferenceError:FB is not defined`

I have referenced the following post which seems to cover a wide array of solutions. [FB is not defined problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5331165/fb-is-not-defined-problem)

The problem specifically I am having is that if I test out my app deploying to the browser, the `fbAsyncInit(...)` is hit in my root `index.html` page.I know this because I put an `alert('fbAsyncInit(..)')` on the first line of the FB init code. For example, if I run the following command, It alerts `fbAsyncInit(..)`

`ionic serve`

As soon as I deploy to a device using the following command, I get no alert and when I try to actually invoke `$cordovaFacebook.login(...)` it gives me the following error:

`ReferenceError: FB is not defined`

My root `index.html` looks similar (removed some stuff for brevity).

```
<html>

    <!-- Other stuff here -->

    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/additional/FacebookConnectPlugin.js"></script>
    <script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        console.log('fbAsyncinit(..)');

        FB.init({
          appId      : '/*App id here*/',
          cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
          xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
          version    : 'v2.1' // use version 2.1
        });


        (function(d, s, id){
             var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
             if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
             js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
             js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
             fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
           }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
      };


    </script>

    <!-- Other Stuff Here -->
</html>
```

The one thing it is hitting is the following piece of code defined in `FacebookConnectPlugin.js`

```
 // Bake in the JS SDK
(function () {
    if (!window.FB) {
        console.log("launching FB SDK");
        var e = document.createElement('script');
        e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js';
        e.async = true;
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
        console.log(window.FB)   //FB is undefined
    }
}());
```

When the script tag loads for `FacebookConnectPlugin.js` and this piece of code runs, it attempts to print `window.FB` to the console, but its undefined.

Any idea what is wrong given the code above?

Comment: place your code inside $ionicPlatform.ready(function() { //code here })

Comment: placing the FB.init and SDK code in the $ionicPlatform.ready(...) did the trick! Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to surround your script by a document ready ?

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  //do work
});
```

Moreover, I do not recommand your to perform this action like that.

You shall :

- define a controller on your app
- add a [$ionicPlatform ready](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPlatform/) event to your controller
- perform your initialisation of your FB plugin in it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ngCordova, not traditional method.

http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/facebook/

Sample code

```
module.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaFacebook) {

  $cordovaFacebook.login(["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"])
    .then(function(success) {
      // { id: "634565435",
      //   lastName: "bob"
      //   ...
      // }
    }, function (error) {
      // error
    });


  var options = {
    method: "feed",
    link: "http://example.com",
    caption: "Such caption, very feed."
  };
  $cordovaFacebook.showDialog(options)
    .then(function(success) {
      // success
    }, function (error) {
      // error
    });


  $cordovaFacebook.api("me", ["public_profile"])
    .then(function(success) {
      // success
    }, function (error) {
      // error
    });


  $cordovaFacebook.getLoginStatus()
    .then(function(success) {
      /*
      { authResponse: {
          userID: "12345678912345",
          accessToken: "kgkh3g42kh4g23kh4g2kh34g2kg4k2h4gkh3g4k2h4gk23h4gk2h34gk234gk2h34AndSoOn",
          session_Key: true,
          expiresIn: "5183738",
          sig: "..."
        },
        status: "connected"
      }
      */
    }, function (error) {
      // error
    });

  $cordovaFacebook.getAccessToken()
    .then(function(success) {
      // success
    }, function (error) {
      // error
    });

  $cordovaFacebook.logout()
    .then(function(success) {
      // success
    }, function (error) {
      // error
    });

});
```

Comment: This is what my code for the $cordovaFacebook.login(...) looks like, but I don't see where your registering the AppID for fb with $cordovaFacebookProvideer. You still need to specify and initialize the FB SDK

Comment: When you install facebook cordova plugin via terminal, it's already registred your AppID automatically. you can check .plist file.